# How to Prove that a (Centered) Gaussian Process is Markov if and only if this Equation Holds?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, markov-process

> A centered Gaussian process is Markov if and only if its covariance
>   function $\Gamma: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
>   the equality:
>
> $$\Gamma(s,u)\Gamma(t,t)=\Gamma(s,t)\Gamma(t,u)\ \ \ \ (1)$$
>
> for all $s<t<u$.

**My Question:** How can you prove this?

It turns out to be difficult to find a clear proof of the above fact. One proof which I found but did not understand well was: Example 4.5, p.119 of *Random Processes for Engineers* by Bruce Hajek, or Example 4.7 on pp. 120-121. The notation used in that book made very little sense to me.

**Background:** Inspired by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772876/markovian-gaussian-stationary-process-with-continuous-paths/1774859#1774859). I had to try and prove the statement for a homework assignment, but was not very successful. A solution was explained in class, but it relied on the rather implausible

**Claim:** A function $h: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies equation (1) if and only if it is of the form $$h=\max(f(s,t),g(s,t))\min(f(s,t),g(s,t))$$for some two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

The sufficiency of the claim to me is clear, but the necessity is not, nor was it proven in class. Moreover, I did not understand anyway the subsequent proof which was supposed to show that the desired equation follows from this claim.

**What I Have Tried:** (Copy-pasted from the TeX file from my homework "solution", which I already handed in and got a grade for)

> Let $X_t$ be a centered Gaussian process. Specifically, $\forall t$,
>   $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=0$ and $X_t \sim \mathscr{N}(0,\sigma_t)$.
>
> Now assume that ab initio $\Gamma(s,u)\Gamma(t,t)=\Gamma(s,t)\Gamma(t,u)$ for any $s<t<u$, but that we have not necessarily shown that $X_t$ is Markov.
>
> Then $\Gamma(s,u)=\frac{\Gamma(s,t)\Gamma(t,u)}{\Gamma(t,t)}$.
>
> Because the process is centered Gaussian, this is true if and only if (see Example 4.5, p.119 of *Random Processes for Engineers* by Bruce Hajek, or Example 4.7 on pp. 120-121.) $X_u$ and $X_s$ are conditionally independent given $X_t$.
>
> This equivalence is due to the fact that the above equation implies that
>   $$\mathbb{E}[(X_s | X_t)(X_u |X_t)]=0,$$ i.e. that the two conditional expectations are uncorrelated, and since the two random variables are Gaussian distributed, this implies even that they are independent.
>
> This is equivalent to the Markov property (past and future are independent given the present).

Comment: Here is one proof: Theorem 8.4 in https://books.google.com/books?id=W5a7k7WmBi4C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=gaussian+process+is+markov+iff+covariance&source=bl&ots=GL-Q_awz5u&sig=OuFGU0ksrO2TWy0qcCI5fFF87-Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnwrrZ1snMAhVI-2MKHV5_CkcQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=gaussian%20process%20is%20markov%20iff%20covariance&f=false

Comment: Thanks! I will try to read it later in the weekend and write it up in a way understandable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I'm answering it anyway because I could have used it.

We want to say that $(X_t)$ gaussian centered process is Markov if and only if $\forall s<r<t$ holds $\Gamma(s,t)\Gamma(r,r)=\Gamma(s,r)\Gamma(t,r)$

In fact if X is Markov then we have
$$ E[X_t|F_s]=E[X_t|X_s]=\frac{\Gamma(s,t)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s $$
where $F_s=\sigma(X_l : l\le s)$ and we use the fact that $X_t - \frac{\Gamma(s,t)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s$ and $X_s$ are indipendent.
But it's also true that
$$E[X_t|F_s]=E[~E[X_t|F_r]~|F_s]=E[\frac{\Gamma(r,t)}{\Gamma(r,r)}X_r|F_s]=\frac{\Gamma(r,t)}{\Gamma(r,r)}\frac{\Gamma(s,r)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s$$
and it conclude.

Now if $\forall s<r<t$ holds $\Gamma(s,t)\Gamma(r,r)=\Gamma(s,r)\Gamma(t,r)$ then we have that $X_t - \frac{\Gamma(s,t)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s$ it is only indipendent from $X_s$ but also from $X_r$ $\forall r<s$ so:
$$E[f(X_t)|F_s]=E[f(X_t - \frac{\Gamma(s,t)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s +y)]|_{y= \frac{\Gamma(s,t)}{\Gamma(s,s)}X_s}$$
it depends only from $X_s$ so it's markov.