# Gauss-Markov characterising property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, markov-process

I am trying to solve exercise no. 1.13 page 86 of 'Continuous time Martingales & Brownian Motion', by Revouz-Yor.
It says that a stochastic process $X_t$ is a Guassian process (i.e. the marginal distributions are all gaussian), and has Markov property, if and only if it is satisfied the relation: $\forall s < t< u, \gamma(s,u)\gamma(t,t)=\gamma(s,t)\gamma(t,u)$,where $\gamma(s,t)=Cov(X_s,X_t)$, the covariance function. A hint I was given is to consider the process as the integral of a Brownian motion, $X_s=\int_{0}^{s}B_rdr$.

Comment: That hint cannot be from Revuz & Yor because $X_s=\int_0^sB_r\,dr$ being Gaussian is not Markov.

Comment: In fact it is not. A friend told me, i tried to work it out but could not find anything

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1774859/949989) mentions a reference for that proof.